# How to show the attached image as the mkv thumbnail?

Tags: file-manager, thumbnails

I have mkv files with covers attached to them. How do I get to show them (when they are there) as the thumbnails in my file manager instead of a random frame ffmpegthumbnailer is usually does? I know some distributions that have this set up. Is it possible to configure a .thumbnailer file to do this or is this bounded to a more 'bloated' file manager?
I generally use Thunar, PCManFM and SpaceFM.

Comment: What is your distribution? Do you have `tumbler` installed?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Arcolinux. I have tumbler installed, but just installed it and didn't use it in any config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least Thunar will ask `tumbler` to create the thumbnails. It is a service over D-bus.

You can configure `tumbler` by modifying `/etc/xdg/tumbler/tumbler.rc` (note that the path could be different in your distribution).

For example, the default for Debian 10 includes both FfmpegThumbnailer and GstThumbnailer:

```
# ffmpegthumbnailer plugin
[FfmpegThumbnailer]
Disabled=false
Priority=2
Locations=
MaxFileSize=0

# GStreamer plugin
[GstThumbnailer]
Disabled=false
Priority=1
Locations=
MaxFileSize=0
```

Edit that file to change the priorities or disable one of them and check.

I don't know how to restart `tumblerd` so you might have to end your graphical session and log in again.

Also note that `~/.cache/thumbnails` already has cached thumbnails. You can test your modifications by copying a new file to a directory and then seeing it with Thunar. Or removing the existing thumbnails, they should be recreated.

Comment: Ok, changing the priority (1 for FfmpegThumbnailer and 2 for GstThumbnailer) and disabling MaxFileSize worked for me.